# Rspec getting "Stack level too deep" from associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

For a controller test, at the top of the spec I'm defining the models:

```
  let(:user) { Factory(:user, :company => company) }
  let(:facility) { Factory(:facility, :company => company) }
  let(:company) { Factory(:company, :facilities => [facility]) }
```

And do the basic index spec:

```
  context "responding to GET index" do
    it "should expose all facilities as @facilities" do
      user.company.should_receive(:facilities).and_return([facility])
      get :index
      assigns[:facilities].should == [facility]
    end
  end
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
should expose all facilities as @facilities
stack level too deep
/Users/dmix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/let.rb:90
88      module InstanceMethods
89        def __memoized # :nodoc:
90          @__memoized ||= {}
91        end
92      end
```

The problem seems to be referencing the 3 Factories at the same time.

If I remove the :facilities from the company factory definition, the stack error goes way:

```
let(:company) { Factory(:company) }
```

How do I factory three models that all reference each other without getting a stackoverflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `facility` and `company` objects reference each other. I think the `:facilities => [facility]` part of your `company` factory may be unnecessary, since you're already designating the `facility` object's company as `company`. Try this:

```
let(:facility) { Factory(:facility, :company => company) }
let(:company) { Factory(:company) }
```

Comment: That indeed fixes the stack too deep error, but it breaks the tests such as:  user.company.should_receive(:facilities).and_return([facility])

Comment: In the test after factory creation, can you simply assign the facility to the company?